# value of JSON Key can be two values and pass

Tags: rest-assured

I have one that may have already been answered. I apologize if it has been, I tried searching for awhile before asking, and didn't find anything specifically for this scenario:

Creating a user, and the API returns a "appStatus": "X"

if X is APPROVE or COMPLETE then the test should pass.

```
            given()
            .header(headers)
            .body(json)
        .when()
            .post(url)
        .then()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .extract().response()
        .then().assertThat()
            .statusCode(200)
        .and()
            .assertThat().body("appStatus", equalTo("APPROVE"))
            .log().all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oneOf(T... elements)` in Hamcrest

```
.assertThat().body("appStatus", oneOf("APPROVE", "COMPLETE"));
```

Comment: oh, duh. Thank you so much! This worked.

Comment: Could you accept this answer? Thank you